# Is angular momentum the conjugate momentum of an angle?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, momentum

[Lagrangian mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) can be used to describe the double pendulum (see [here](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/DoublePendulum.html), for example). In this development are the conjugate [momenta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum) $p_{\theta_i}$ exactly the angular momenta $m_i l_i \frac{d \theta_i}{dt}$?

In other words, do the following sequences hold:

- Position ->  Velocity -> Momentum
- Angle -> Angular velocity -> Angular momentum
- Generalized coordinate ->    Generalized velocity -> Conjugate momentum

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you ask *"does the following sequences hold"*.

Comment: The question seems pretty clear to me. (The answer is just "yes.")

Comment: I'm not convinced - the naming similarity and arguments based on dimensions aren't really compelling. I'll need to think about a bit more.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Can you answer the question?

Comment: ACuriousMind shows more of his broadmindedness.

Answer (score 3):

You are right. If $q$ is a generalized coordinate then $\dot{q}$ is the generalized velocity and hence the generalized momentum is
\begin{equation}
p = \frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q}}
\end{equation}
Therefore, your sequence looks correct. Further, equations (20) and (21) of the article you have referenced also tell that the $p_{\theta_i}$ are indeed angular momenta. (You may want to check the dimensions.)

Normally, when we speak of angular momentum as a vector, we refer to a certain origin. In this case, we do not have to do it. The conjugate variable $p$ in this case, "happens to be" angular momentum.